# Java select list attribute via another way

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a question. I have recently started diving into Java and was wondering if it was possible to select an list attribute like this

list["attribute"]? I want this because I have a list and want to give an attribute to a method and so that I can dynamically select the value of the list attribute.

Is this possible and if not how can I best approach this?

Edit:
I am trying to make random questions and I have this piece of code that I want to put in a method so that I do not have to copy paste my code.

```
question = generateQuestion("Is he older than * years old?", attributes.age);
    System.out.println(question.get("question"));
    input = br.readLine();
    var attribute1 = question;
    var isOlder = input.contains("yes");
    list = list.stream().filter(person -> (person.age > Integer.parseInt(attribute1.get("attributeName"))) == isOlder).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you can see I use a list stream and in that list stream I have person.age but I want the ".age" part dynamic.

Comment: Java being a statically typed language, you have to avoid thinking as if it were a dynamically typed one. Accessing a field dynamically can be done, but it's not usually a smart way to go. You should think of a different design (involving deciding up front **which** attributes you want to do comparisons with).

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of attributes where Item is the class the list of instances you have.

```
    list.stream()
        .map(Item::getAttribute())
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

BTW Groovy supports spread operator to make it easier:

```
list*.attribute
```